# Get the text value of selected option using this keyword in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to get the text value of the *selected* option using *this* keyword

For e.g.:

`$(this).val()` will give me the value of the selected option.

What I want is the text if the option was selected, but using *this* keyword.

Comment: Is `this` the `option` or the `select`?

Comment: the currently selected option

Comment: Well the use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: By using `$(this).children(":selected").text();`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: `$(this).children(":selected").text();`

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {


  $("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
    var text = $(this).children(":selected").text();
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log("Text: " + text + " Value: " + value);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="One">1</option>
  <option value="Two">2</option>
</select>
```